# destroy GUI elements

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am new to C# programming migrated  from python. I made two windows forms application which are connected to a single third application by a menu button when the first menu button is clicked the first W.F.A. appears and when the second button is clicked the second W.F.A. appears.
What is happening now is when the first button is clicked it load the desired windows forms but after that when the second button is clicked the second windows form overlaps the first one with out destroying the first one. What I need is that whenever the new windows form is loaded it should destroy the previous windows forms. I hope, I made myself clear. what can I do to achieve this ?
Here are my codes?

```
//something.Designer.cs
namespace Demo
{
 partial class Demo
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.enterDataToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.showDataToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripSeparator1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
        this.exitToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.label9 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // menuStrip1
        // 
        this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem});
        this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
        this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(426, 24);
        this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
        // 
        // fileToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.enterDataToolStripMenuItem,
        this.showDataToolStripMenuItem,
        this.toolStripSeparator1,
        this.exitToolStripMenuItem});
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fileToolStripMenuItem";
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File";
        // 
        // enterDataToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this.enterDataToolStripMenuItem.Name = "enterDataToolStripMenuItem";
        this.enterDataToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        this.enterDataToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Enter Data";
        this.enterDataToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.enterDataToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        // 
        // showDataToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this.showDataToolStripMenuItem.Name = "showDataToolStripMenuItem";
        this.showDataToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        this.showDataToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Show Data";
        this.showDataToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.showDataToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripSeparator1
        // 
        this.toolStripSeparator1.Name = "toolStripSeparator1";
        this.toolStripSeparator1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 6);
        // 
        // exitToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this.exitToolStripMenuItem.Name = "exitToolStripMenuItem";
        this.exitToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        this.exitToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Exit";
        this.exitToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.exitToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        // 
        // label9
        // 
        this.label9.AutoSize = true;
        this.label9.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 72F, ((System.Drawing.FontStyle)((System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold | System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic))), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label9.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(131, 118);
        this.label9.Name = "label9";
        this.label9.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 108);
        this.label9.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label9.Text = "ZK";
        // 
        // Demo
        // 
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(426, 324);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label9);
        this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
        this.Name = "Demo";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "ZK";
        this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    private void showData()
    {
        this.label9.Text = "";
        this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.studentData = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.studentID = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gNo = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.studName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.fathName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.mobNum = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.dOBirth = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.studentData)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label8
        // 
        this.label8.AutoSize = true;
        this.label8.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 48F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(267, 35);
        this.label8.Name = "label8";
        this.label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(116, 73);
        this.label8.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label8.Text = "ZK";
        this.label8.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        // 
        // studentData
        // 
        this.studentData.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.studentData.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        this.studentData.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.studentData.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Raised;
        this.studentData.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.studentData.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.studentID,
        this.gNo,
        this.studName,
        this.fathName,
        this.mobNum,
        this.dOBirth});
        this.studentData.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
        this.studentData.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 144);
        this.studentData.Name = "studentData";
        this.studentData.ReadOnly = true;
        this.studentData.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.studentData.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
        this.studentData.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(618, 365);
        this.studentData.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // studentID
        // 
        this.studentID.HeaderText = "Student ID";
        this.studentID.Name = "studentID";
        this.studentID.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // gNo
        // 
        this.gNo.HeaderText = "Gr. No.";
        this.gNo.Name = "gNo";
        this.gNo.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // studName
        // 
        this.studName.HeaderText = "Student Name";
        this.studName.Name = "studName";
        this.studName.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // fathName
        // 
        this.fathName.HeaderText = "Father Name";
        this.fathName.Name = "fathName";
        this.fathName.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // mobNum
        // 
        this.mobNum.HeaderText = "Mobile No";
        this.mobNum.Name = "mobNum";
        this.mobNum.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // dOBirth
        // 
        this.dOBirth.HeaderText = "Date Of Birth";
        this.dOBirth.Name = "dOBirth";
        this.dOBirth.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // Demo
        // 
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(642, 521);
        this.Controls.Add(this.studentData);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label8);
        this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Desktop;
        this.Name = "Demo";
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.Text = "ZK";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.fillTable);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.studentData)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    private void EnterData()
    {
        this.label9.Text = "";
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.grNo = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.studentName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.fatherName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.mobNo = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.dob = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
        this.saveBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.status = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 48F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(234, 24);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(116, 73);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "ZK";
        this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 195);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 24);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "Gr. No.";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(225, 111);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 29);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 3;
        this.label3.Text = "Enter Data";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this.label4.AutoSize = true;
        this.label4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 358);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 24);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label4.Text = "Date of Birth";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this.label5.AutoSize = true;
        this.label5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 317);
        this.label5.Name = "label5";
        this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 24);
        this.label5.TabIndex = 5;
        this.label5.Text = "Mobile No.";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this.label6.AutoSize = true;
        this.label6.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 279);
        this.label6.Name = "label6";
        this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(133, 24);
        this.label6.TabIndex = 6;
        this.label6.Text = "Father\'s Name";
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this.label7.AutoSize = true;
        this.label7.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 236);
        this.label7.Name = "label7";
        this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 24);
        this.label7.TabIndex = 7;
        this.label7.Text = "Student\'s Name";
        // 
        // grNo
        // 
        this.grNo.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.grNo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(274, 195);
        this.grNo.Name = "grNo";
        this.grNo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 24);
        this.grNo.TabIndex = 8;
        // 
        // studentName
        // 
        this.studentName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.studentName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(274, 236);
        this.studentName.Name = "studentName";
        this.studentName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 24);
        this.studentName.TabIndex = 9;
        // 
        // fatherName
        // 
        this.fatherName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.fatherName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(274, 279);
        this.fatherName.Name = "fatherName";
        this.fatherName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 24);
        this.fatherName.TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // mobNo
        // 
        this.mobNo.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.mobNo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(274, 317);
        this.mobNo.Name = "mobNo";
        this.mobNo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 24);
        this.mobNo.TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // dob
        // 
        this.dob.CalendarFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.dob.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(274, 361);
        this.dob.Name = "dob";
        this.dob.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(236, 20);
        this.dob.TabIndex = 12;
        // 
        // saveBtn
        // 
        this.saveBtn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
        this.saveBtn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 5;
        this.saveBtn.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.saveBtn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Desktop;
        this.saveBtn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.saveBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(413, 399);
        this.saveBtn.Name = "saveBtn";
        this.saveBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 36);
        this.saveBtn.TabIndex = 13;
        this.saveBtn.Text = "Save";
        this.saveBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.saveBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.saveBtn_Click);
        // 
        // status
        // 
        this.status.AutoSize = true;
        this.status.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.status.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 153);
        this.status.Name = "status";
        this.status.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(165, 20);
        this.status.TabIndex = 14;
        this.status.Text = "                                       ";
        // 
        // Demo
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 463);
        this.Controls.Add(this.status);
        this.Controls.Add(this.saveBtn);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dob);
        this.Controls.Add(this.mobNo);
        this.Controls.Add(this.fatherName);
        this.Controls.Add(this.studentName);
        this.Controls.Add(this.grNo);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label7);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Name = "Demo";
        this.Text = "ZK";
        //this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Demo_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox grNo;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox studentName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox fatherName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox mobNo;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker dob;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button saveBtn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label status;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView studentData;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn studentID;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gNo;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn studName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn fathName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn mobNum;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dOBirth;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip menuStrip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem fileToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem enterDataToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem        showDataToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem exitToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label9;
}
}


 //something.cs
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections.Specialized;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Demo
{
public partial class Demo : Form
{
    protected class Details
    {
        private List<NameValueCollection> detail = new List<NameValueCollection>();

        public void addDetails(string id,string gr,string sName,string fName,string mob,string dob)
        {
            NameValueCollection dict = new NameValueCollection();
            dict["id"] = id;
            dict["GrNo"] = gr;
            dict["sName"] = sName;
            dict["fName"] = fName;
            dict["mob"] = mob;
            dict["dob"] = dob;
            detail.Add(dict);
        }

        public List<NameValueCollection> getDetails()
        {
            return detail;
        }
    }

    public Demo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(grNo.Text != "")
        {
            if(studentName.Text != "")
            {
                if(fatherName.Text != "")
                {
                    if(mobNo.Text != "")
                    {
                        bool isDone = saveAction(grNo.Text, studentName.Text, fatherName.Text, mobNo.Text, dob.Value);
                        if(isDone)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully added!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool saveAction(string gr, string sName, string fName, string mob, DateTime dob)
    {
        string sqlDetails = "Data Source=DESKTOP-DBJ8T78\\sql;Initial Catalog=Demo;User ID=sa;Password=sample";
        SqlConnection dbHandle = new SqlConnection(sqlDetails);
        try
        {
            dbHandle.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM studentDetails WHERE GrNo='"+gr+"'";
            SqlCommand result = new SqlCommand(sql, dbHandle);
            SqlDataReader row = result.ExecuteReader();
            if(!row.Read())
            {
                row.Close();
                result.Dispose();
                sql = "INSERT INTO studentDetails (GrNo,StudentName,FatherName,MobileNo,DOB) VALUES ('" + gr + "','" + sName + "','" + fName + "','" + mob + "','" + dob + "')";
                result = new SqlCommand(sql, dbHandle);
                result.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                status.Text = "Gr. No. '" + gr + "' Already Exists!";
                row.Close();
                result.Dispose();
                dbHandle.Close();
                return false;
            }
            row.Close();
            result.Dispose();
            dbHandle.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            status.Text = "Connection to the Database Failed! Please Contact Administrator for further details. \n" + e;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void fillTable(object sender,EventArgs ev)
    {
        string sqlDetails = "Data Source=DESKTOP-DBJ8T78\\sql;Initial Catalog=Demo;User ID=sa;Password=sample";
        SqlConnection dbHandle = new SqlConnection(sqlDetails);
        try
        {
            dbHandle.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM studentDetails";
            SqlCommand result = new SqlCommand(sql, dbHandle);
            SqlDataReader row = result.ExecuteReader();
            Details student = new Details();
            while(row.Read())
            {
                student.addDetails(row.GetValue(0).ToString(),row.GetValue(1).ToString(), row.GetValue(2).ToString(), row.GetValue(3).ToString(), row.GetValue(4).ToString(), row.GetValue(5).ToString());
            }
            List<NameValueCollection> sDetails = student.getDetails();
            foreach(NameValueCollection data in sDetails)
            {
                this.studentData.Rows.Add(data["id"], data["GrNo"], data["sName"], data["fName"], data["mob"], data["dob"]);
            }
            row.Close();
            result.Dispose();
            dbHandle.Close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some Error Occured! Please Contact Administrator.\n" + e);
        }
    }

    private void enterDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.EnterData();
    }

    private void showDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.showData();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the code?

Comment: You need to share your code here, so others could understand what your issue is.

Comment: code included..

Comment: A bit too much code included :-) I am assuming that the two pop-ups are EnterData and ShowData, correct?

Comment: @DavidSetty Yes you are correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what you have done is created the other winforms as a part of the original Form1.  What you should be doing is creating a **new** form for EnterData and for SaveData.

Right-click on the project name and select "Add" -> "New Item..." from the pop-up menu.  This will take you to the Add New Item dialog.  Select "Winfows Form". In the name box, name it either EnterForm or SaveForm, whichever one you are doing.  Then the initialisation for each of these forms will go in their own classes.

Then, when the toolbar is clicked, you call the individual form:

```
enterForm = new EnterForm();
if (saveForm != null)
{
    saveForm.Close();
    saveForm = null;
}

enterForm.Show();
```

This is just a basic run down.  I suggest that you run through some basic Winforms training to get used to the paradigm.

Comment: sir it almost worked but there is a little problem when I try to open the second event after executing the first and closing that dialog it crashes with `System.NullReferenceException`. I tried to troubleshoot this by removing the `if` block , then when i open the first element then second element and then again the first it crashes again with `System.ObjectDisposedException` what can be done here

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of the dialogs each time?

Answer (score 0):

I see what you trying to tell.
Every Form has a return value after close. When you call MessageBox.Show() and then close it by pressing "Ok" button, you can check returned value (DialogResult) and do some actions:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("done") == DialogResult.OK)
    this.Close();
```

Comment: I cant understand what you are trying to say. There is no variable `form1` and `form2` in my code. Is there any `hide` or `destroy` like method for the methods `EnterData()` and `showData()` in the above code provided? I would like to inform you that I am a Beginner with C# so please explain in reference to my code. Thanks!